# Variable set in code block does not retain its value

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Newbie question... I am trying to set a variable self.projectName in a code block but when I call it outside the code block, the value is not retained.  After reading more about code blocks, it seems like there are some rules on when values become available but I'm still not clear why I can't set the value for use later...any help would be much appreciated!

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ScheduledProjects"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *projects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFObject *project = [projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.projectName = project[@"name"];
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];

NSLog (@"project name = %@",self.projectName);
```

Comment: Please, show us how the property is defined. It probably is an issue with the property being `weak` or `assign`. Also, the code after the block (the block is asynchronous) runs before the block completes, so it has no value yet.

Comment: Learn about asynchronous processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block is meant to be called asynchronously, which means that after you defined it you don't know exactly when it will finish executing.
To use the variable try creating a callback function and calling it at the end of the block. There you will know for sure that it has been executed.

Example:

```
-(void)yourMethod{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ScheduledProjects"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *projects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
            PFObject *project = [projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.projectName = project[@"name"];
        [self callback];//You call the method when your block is finished
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //Here you could call a different callback for error handling (or passing a success param)
    }
}];

}

-(void) callback{
    //Here you know the code has been executed
    NSLog (@"project name = %@",self.projectName);
}
```

Comment: makes total sense.  Thanks so much for your help!